# Fetch records using relative time interval condition

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Is it possible to fetch records using relative time interval, let's say I want to see all records satisfying the following formula:

`(NOW() - model.deliveryDate) > 24_HOURS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
(NOW() - 24_HOURS) > model.deliveryDate
```

which, in js would translate to something like:

```
var aDayInMs = 1000 * 60  * 60 * 24, 
    aDayAgo = new Date(new Date().getTime() - aDayInMs);

query.lessThan('deliveryDate', aDayAgo);
```

edited to get the query actually working as specified.

Comment: I guess I was trying to solve the problem from the absolutely opposite way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only thing is, it should be lessThan instead of greaterThan.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ... Use javascript Date object .... Have a look at this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_date_object.htm

Comment: Can you give me example in context of Parse.Query?